# How do you extract the first sentence in Excel

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

I have around 2000 descriptions that need a short description. Here is an example of a description.

**Chloe New, the heir of the Original Chloe is warm, feminine and a great signature scent. Chloe is a flowery scent with peonies, freesia, magnolia, lilies and rose petals along with ripe litchis. A hint of woods at the base makes Chloe New the best everyday fragrance. It's long lasting power keeps you fresh all day long.**

The result being this

**Chloe New, the heir of the Original Chloe is warm, feminine and a great signature scent.**

Sometimes other descriptions will end like this, for example:

**Chloe New, the heir of the Original Chloe is warm, feminine and a great signature scent. Chloe is**

The current function I am using is the "=left(a1,70)" which takes the first 70 characters starting from the left. However, this function doesn't always extract the first sentence but ends at the beginning of the second sentence.

So my question is:

Is there a function that only extracts the first sentence of a cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a "space" right after "." to prevent the sentence from being prematurely trimmed in the case of an abbreviation like "e.g.":

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(". ",A1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Where A1 is the cell you are evaluating:

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(".",A1))
```

`SEARCH()` finds the index of "." and you evaluate your `LEFT()` function up to that point.

**EDIT:** For this use case, my solution and Gary's solution are nearly identical.  For other use cases, `SEARCH` might be preferable to `FIND` because it performs case-insensitive search and also supports wildcard characters.

Comment: If `SEARCH` supports wildcards, there might (should?) be a performance hit.  For 2000 records, this could be noticeable.  This becomes more important as more is added to the workbook, particularly if `Calculations` are set to Automatic.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to tag off the comma use this:

```
=LEFT(A1, (SEARCH(",",A1,1))-1)
```